# Is it possible to preserve explored map progress when deleting chunks from the savefile/uploading it to a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The situation is that I need to set up a server to host a game previously was only local.
I tried hamachi, but it disconnects immediately (I blame the intercontinental lag since it works otherwise, but if you think it is something else, let's talk in chat). As a consequence, now I'm trying with minehut.

As we like to explore, the save was beyond 2gb, so I trimmed it with MCAselector.

Now my question: we had made a giant map wall. After the trim, if I load the world locally, the map wall shows as before, but if I upload the save to minehut and log into the server, the maps are either missing or wrong/garbled.

I tried uploading the individual map_###.dat files and for some maps it helped, but not all.
Is there a way to preserve those maps? or should I give up and re-explore everything?

Comment: Did you try locking the maps using cartographer table and glass panes?

Comment: @SF. no, but given the info on the minecraft wiki the glass panes should not have effect on this issue. glass panes basically set the "color" field of the dat file to "unwritable", but the only write operation should be when you hold the map, not when is in an item frame, no?
still, I solved by re-uploading, so hopefully I don't need this test

Answer (score 1):

I solved by re-uploading the world and uploading the map_###.dat files again before logging in the uploaded world.